# How does a UIViewControllerRepresentable of a TableViewController handle navigation?

Tags: swiftui

In my app I have a UIKit ContactsTableViewController that presents a list of contacts and when a contact is pressed the navigation controller presents a DetailViewController.
Now I want to re-use that ContactsTableViewController in SwiftUI so I have created a UIViewControllerRepresentable and I have moved the the tableVIew(tableView: didSelectRowAt:) methods here but now I cannot just push the DetailsViewController to the NavigationController because I don't have a reference of it.
So How can this be done?

```
struct ContactView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let viewModel: ContactsViewModel

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ContactsTableViewController {
        let vc = ContactsTableViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
        vc.tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ContactsTableViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}

extension ContactView {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {
        var parent: ContactView

        init(_ parent: ContactView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // Get the selected contact
            let contact = parent.viewModel.contacts[indexPath.row]

            // Create a view model for the detail view
            let dependencies: DetailsViewModel.Dependencies = .init(contacts: parent.viewModel.contacts, contactMethod: contact.contactMethod)
            let viewModel = DetailsViewModel(dependencies: dependencies)

            // Present the detail view controller
            let detailsViewController = viewModel.detailViewControllerFactory(viewModel.contacts, selectedContact.contactMethod)
     
     
 //navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsViewController, animated: true)
            
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator(self)
    }
}

struct Contacts_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let dependencies = Dependencies()
    static var previews: some View {
        ContactView(viewModel: dependencies.contactsViewModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `Coordinator` for the tableview delegate, you can implement tableview delegate in `ContactsTableViewController` and pass `viewModel` inside it so that you will have the full control over navigation inside the controller. It will be more efficient than the current one.

Comment: @ChrisR, of course it is a SwiftUI question. UIViewControllerRepresentable is a SwiftUI protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinator isn’t set up right, here is the proper way:

```
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator()
    }

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ContactsTableViewController {
        context.coordinator.contactsTableViewController
    }
```

You must also implement `updateUIViewController` and use the struct's new values in the `let`s and `@Binding vars` to update the `Coordinator` and/or the `UIViewController`. In your case you would set the selected contact and set a closure for for setting a controller selected contact on the new binding.

Now in the Coordinator you can do:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, ContactsTableViewControllerDelegate {
        
    lazy var contactsTableViewController: ContactsTableViewController = {
        let vc = ContactsTableViewController()
        vc.delegate = self
        return vc
    }()

    func contactsTableViewController(_ contactsTableViewController: ContactsTableViewController, didSelectContact: Contact) {
        ... 
        contactsTableViewController.showViewController(detailsViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

Lastly, best remove any UIKit view models, in SwiftUI the View struct already is one.

Comment: your answer is unclear: the context.coordinator.contactsTableViewController that you use is not defined anywhere in the Coordinator since you are initializing as Coordinator()

Comment: I added some more code

Comment: I get the idea, and with that input I resolved the problem, so I'm accepting your answer. Regarding the suggestion to remove the UIKit models, I don't think it suits my needs: I have already them implemented  and I want to reuse them rather that having them duplicated. My aim is to reuse the existing viewModels still supporting both SwiftUI and UIKit ( for older version of the iOS)